# Request scoped caching for Non-IIS hosted WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, caching, request

I am using IIS hosted WCF services with request-scoped caching through the Http context. This is useful for example to cache an EF data context. Now I want to switch to another Non-IIS hosted environment without Http context. What are the options to implement a request scoped caching in general WCF environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `OperationContext` by implementing `IExtension<OperationContext>`. By implementing extension you can define what you want to store in `OperationContext`. [Here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/17/abstracting-request-state/) you have nice blog about abstracting request state.

Comment: Thanks’ for that. It is exactly what I'm searching :-)